# Is a value present in certain columns of a dataframe (by row)? Using %in% and | on multiple columns works, but is there a more concise way?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks something like

```
> df = data.frame(c1=c(3,6,NA,5), c2=c(2,NA,3,NA), c3=c(1,4,4,2))
> df
  c1 c2 c3
1  3  2  1
2  6 NA  4
3 NA  3  4
4  5 NA  2
```

I would like to create additional columns that record, by each row, whether a given value is present in c1 or c2, ignoring c3.

This works but is not concise (especially with my actual data):

```
> df$is.2.in.c1.or.c2[df$c1 %in% 2 | df$c2 %in% 2] = 'It is there'
> df
  c1 c2 c3 is.2.in.c1.or.c2
1  3  2  1      It is there
2  6 NA  4             <NA>
3 NA  3  4             <NA>
4  5 NA  2             <NA>
```

Is there a more concise way?

Comment: You could also use `apply`: `df$c4 <- 0`     `df[which(apply(df[,1:2],1,function(x) 2 %in% x)),"c4"] <- 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `rowSums` after creating a logical matrix using `==`.

```
i1 <- rowSums(df[1:2]==2, na.rm=TRUE)!=0
```

It is better to have a logical index ('i1') instead of flagging with 'It is there'.  But, if needed,

```
ifelse(i1, 'It is there', NA)
#[1] "It is there" NA            NA            NA
```